# Jquery not disabling dropdown item when requested

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to disable a dropdown item after I select it and click a button. I'm using Jquery and the code looks like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#AddProduct", function () {
            var id = $("#ProductDrop").val();
            var lookups = JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Point.Properties["Lookups"])));
            var data = JSON.stringify({ productId: id, lookupData: lookups });
            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: '/Edit/AddRow',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#ProductDrop option[value = \""+id+"\"]").prop("disabled", true)
                    $("#tableBody").append(data);
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
```

On success of the ajax request I want to disable the dropdown item.

When I run this code the markup looks like this:

```
<div class="ui dropdown selection" tabindex="0">
    <select id="ProductDrop" name="Products">
        <option disabled="disabled" value="1">AWV</option>
        <option disabled="disabled" value="2">AWS</option>
        <option value="3" disabled="">AGZ</option>
        <option value="4">AMZ</option>
        <option value="5">WWV</option>
        <option value="6">WWS</option>
        <option value="7">WTS</option>
        <option value="8">WME-B Gen2</option>
        <option value="9">WTC</option>
        <option value="10">WCT</option>
        <option value="11">WMT</option>
        <option value="14">WCT-Gen2</option>
    </select>
    <i class="dropdown icon clear"></i>
    <div class="text">AGZ</div>
    <div class="menu" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="disabled item" data-value="1">AWV</div>
        <div class="disabled item" data-value="2">AWS</div>
        <div class="item active selected" data-value="3">AGZ</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="4">AMZ</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="5">WWV</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="6">WWS</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="7">WTS</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="8">WME-B Gen2</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="9">WTC</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="10">WCT</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="11">WMT</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="14">WCT-Gen2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The item is disabled in select but not in menu (and is still selectable in the webpage). My razor code for creating the dropdown is this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Products",(List<SelectListItem>)Model.Point.Properties["PossibleProducts"], new { @class="ui dropdown", @id = "ProductDrop"})
```

I'm not really sure why this code isn't working. I assume it has something to do with the item not being disabled in the menu markup, but I have no idea how I would go about disabling that. Is there something wrong with how I'm creating the dropdown menu?

Comment: *"item is not disabled in the menu"* - you don't have any js code that attempts to disable it in the menu, only on the select (which you say is working)

Comment: *"not disabling dropdown item"* / *"disabled in select"* - only the `select` is a "dropdown item"- so your question is that it's not working, then you state it is working.  Please update the question with the *actual* problem (dropdown menu not disabling perhaps? something else?)

Comment: Are you using a custom dropdown plugin?